# Cytoscape: dynamic network visualization

Tags: r, igraph, cytoscape

I’m using R to send graph objects (igraph) to Cytoscape via a RESTful API – which is working perfectly.
The trouble I’m having is that the graphs are dynamic and each node/edge has a creation/end date, is it possible to do dynamic visualisation in Cytoscape? I’ve tried using a number of different plugins including dynNetwork however this looks for a network file in XGMML format.

Has anyone come across a Cytoscape plugin to do this type of work?

Or failing that, is there a R package to output igraph objects in a XGMML format?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Cytoscape, but it is possible to visualize dynamic networks in R with the `ndtv` and `networkDynamic` packages (disclaimer, I'm the package author)